# C# LazyList for lots of entries

Tags: c#, lazy-evaluation

I recently became aware of the notion of LazyList, and I would like to implement this notion in my work.

I have serveral methods which may retrieve hundreds of thousands of entries from the database, I want to return a `LazyList<T>` rather than a typical `List<T>`.

I could only find `Lazy<List<T>>` which is, as to my understanding, not the same. The `Lazy<List<T>>` makes the initialization of the list lazy, thats not what I need.

I want to give an example from Scheme language, if someone ever used it.

Basically it is implemented by `LinkedNodes`wheras the value of a given node needs to be calculated and the `node.next` is actually a function which needed to be calculated to retrieve the value.

I wonder how to actually control lists in size of 400k or so, It sounds like its so expensive to hold a List in the size of couple of MB which, possibly, can get to GBs depends on the db operation the program needs to do.

Im currently using .Net 4.5, C# version is 4

Comment: @Claies i thought about it, but when i retrieve the data from the db i already have an instance of an object..how do i handle with the reinstanstation again?

Comment: instance of which type? Maybe it already has deferred evaluation, as many of types that implement IEnumerable have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of returning a `List<T>` or `LazyList`, why not yield return the results? This is much better than retrieving all rows. It will stream it row by row. Better for memory management.

For example:  *(PSEUDO)*

```
private IEnumerator<Row> GetRows(SqlConnection connection)
{
    var resultSet = connection.ExecuteQuery(.....);
    resultSet.Open();
    try
    {
        while(resultSet.FetchNext())
        {
            // read one row..
            yield return row;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        resultSet.Close();
    }
}

foreach(var row in GetRows(connection))
{
    // handle the row.

}
```

This way each the result set is handled each row.

Comment: Care to explain how yield is solving this for me?

Comment: you know how it will work with mongodb driver AsyncCursor by mistake?

Comment: yield prevents reading all rows at ones. Everytime the foreach iterate the `IEnumerator<Row>` it will get the next row from the resultset. For more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx

Comment: No, never used mongodb, but if someone uses a list with huge amount of items, yield might be a solution

Comment: Thanks alot. is there any way to change the response to list instead of IEnumerable without affecting the performance?

Comment: No, a list would cause the enumerable to be fully enumerated. You must work with the IEnumerable.  J